# Create a stream of the values in maps that are values in another map in Java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Sorry about the title of the question; it was kind of hard for me to make sense of it.  If you guys have a better title, let me know and I can change it.

I have two types of objects, Bookmark and Revision.  I have one large Map, like so:

```
Map<Long, Bookmark> mapOfBookmarks;
```

it contains key: value pairs like so:

```
1L: Bookmark1,
2L: Bookmark2,
...
```

Each Bookmark has a 'getRevisions()' method that returns a Map

```
public Map<Long, Revision> getRevisions();
```

I want to create a Stream that contains all revisions that exist under mapOfBookmarks.  Essentially I want to do this:

```
List<Revision> revisions = new ArrayList<>();
for (Bookmark bookmark : mapOfBookmarks.values()) { // loop through each bookmark in the map of bookmarks ( Map<Long, Bookmark> )
    for (Revision revision : bookmark.getRevisions().values()) { // loop through each revision in the map of revisions ( Map<Long, Revision> )
        revisions.add(revision);  // add each revision of each map to the revisions list
    }
}
return revisions.stream(); // return a stream of revisions
```

However, I'd like to do it using the functionality of Stream, so more like:

```
return mapOfBookmarks.values().stream().everythingElseThatIsNeeded();
```

Which would essentially be like saying:

```
return Stream.of(revision1, revision2, revision3, revision4, ...);
```

How would I write that out? Something to note is that the dataset that it is looping through can be huge, making the list method a poor approach.

I'm using Windows 7 and Java 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the [`flatMap(mapper)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) operation:

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of replacing each element of this stream with the contents of a mapped stream produced by applying the provided mapping function to each element.

In this case, we're making a `Stream<Bookmark>` by calling [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--), flat mapping it to the revisions of each bookmark and, finally, collecting that into a list with [`toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--).

```
List<Revision> revisions = 
    mapOfBookmarks.values()
                  .stream()
                  .flatMap(bookmark -> boormark.getRevisions().values().stream())
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Note that your current code could also be improved by calling [`addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) instead of looping over each revisions:

```
for (Bookmark bookmark : mapOfBookmarks.values()) { // loop through each bookmark in the map of bookmarks ( Map<Long, Bookmark> )
    revisions.addAll(bookmark.getRevisions().values());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A `flatmap` is what you looking for. When you have streams contained within a stream that you wish to flatten, then `flatmap` is the answer,

```
List<Revision> all =
    mapOfBookmarks.values().stream()
        .flatMap(c -> c.getRevisions().values().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```